# cannot read file in a function after writing to it in another function

Tags: c, string, file

I want to write to a file in a function called `func1`, read this file in `main` and store the line in a string `fname`. I have something like:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include<string.h>


  int func(){

    FILE *fp=NULL;
       if ( ( fp= fopen("file.dat","w+")) == NULL){
                printf("Couldn't open file file.dat \n");
                exit(-1);
        }
    fprintf(fp,"%s \n","This is file.dat");
    return(0);
    } 


int main(){

        FILE *fp;
        char fname[1000]="stringInit";
        func();
        if ( ( fp= fopen("file.dat","r")) == NULL){
                printf("Couldn't open file file.dat \n");
                exit(-1);
        }

        fgets(fname,1000,fp);
        printf(" fname = %s \n",fname);

        fclose(fp);

 return(0);

 }
```

I am getting `fname= stringInit`, I guess because `file.dat` was not created since it is closed in the end of the `main` only. So my question is: are there any other solutions beside using an array of string in the function `func`?

Comment: This shouldn't compile: `fprintf(fp,"%s \n",This is file.dat);`

Comment: Close the file: `fclose(fp);` just before returning from `func`

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the file:

```
int func(){

    FILE *fp=NULL;
       if ( ( fp= fopen("file.dat","w+")) == NULL){
                printf("Couldn't open file file.dat \n");
                exit(-1);
        }
    fprintf(fp,"%s \n", "This is file.dat");
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

You can also return the file handle:

```
FILE *func(void){

    FILE *fp=NULL;
       if ( ( fp= fopen("file.dat","w+")) == NULL){
                printf("Couldn't open file file.dat \n");
                exit(-1);
        }
    fprintf(fp,"%s \n", "This is file.dat");
    return fp;
} 


int main(void){

    FILE *fp;
    char fname[1000]="stringInit";
    fp = func();
    if (fp == NULL){
            printf("Couldn't open file galactic_coord.dat \n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fgets(fname,1000,fp);
    printf(" fname = %s \n",fname);

    fclose(fp);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: In my complete program I was actually closing the file in `func` but inside a loop, so this is the reason why it was not working...